# Disable NamedParameterJdbcTemplate caching

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I want to change result set behavior of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. (disable result set caching)

For example , with postgres jdbc driver you could change it like this:

```
        conn = datasource.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        stmt.setFetchSize(50);
```

How i can achieve it in spring / spring-boot ?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to change a `fetchSize` then you can do it through a `JdbcTemplate` instance:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
```

**UPD**

Speaking of cache changing you may try to change a `private volatile int cacheLimit` of the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` instance:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
template.setCacheLimit(0);
```

it possible but i didn't explore it

Comment: No the goal is to disable result set caching. For big sqls is a change u can get out of memory.

Comment: stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);     This line controls result set behaviour , but i didn t found a way to change the result set in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

Comment: Then sorry for a probably stupid question but wich one of four lines in your example is disabling caching? It looks like you are only setting a fetch size and fetching mode
UPD: you wrote there _For example , with postgres jdbc driver you could change it like this_

Comment: Statement parameters : java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY

Comment: And i tried the cacheLimit. Not working or i am not using it right..Tried to set it to 0,-1 and 1 and same behavior ram is heavy charged.